# database conenction not successful between nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

```
var fs = require('fs');

var mongo = require("mongodb");

var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json'));

var host = config.host;

var port = mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;

var db = new mongo.Db("Nodejs-introduction", new mongo.Server(host,port,{}));

db.open(function(error){
console.log("we are connected " + host + " : " + port );

db.collection("user",function(error,collection){
    console.log("we have the collection");

    collection.insert({
        name:"jarvis"
    }, function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err;

        console.log(result);

        db.close();
    });

});
```

});

For the above program. I get the following error on command prompt
[image]

Error after changes are below :

[image]

Comment: Actually in this listing you never close the callback after `db.collection`. So where does it actually close? That type error is indicating that you probably referenced something that is out of scope.

Comment: @NeilLunn Solved the problem by installing mongodb properly. i assumed mongodb got installed but turns out it did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by Re installing Mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is fine, I think problem may be in here

```
collection.insert({
    name: "jarvis"
}, function(err,result){
    console.log(err);
});
```

You may have problem tryin to log err while there is no error with that insert. Try making it:

```
collection.insert({
    name: "jarvis"
}, function(err,result){
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log(result);

    db.close();
});
```

And remember to close db.

Comment: the error did not resolve I will post the error below after making the changes.

Comment: Solved the problem by installing mongodb properly. i assumed mongodb got installed but turns out it did not.